# OpenGL Weird Red Green and Blue Lines on Cube Map and Repeating Three Times

Tags: c++, opengl

Please check following image:

[image]

I cannot figure out why this is happening, it just doesn’t make sense, I’ve checked it over and over and it keeps showing the same thing, three of the same image on each side of the skybox and red, green and blue stripes going down them.

What am I doing wrong?

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400
in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 mvp;
out vec3 tex;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
    tex = position;
}
```

Fragmant Shader:

```
#version 400
uniform samplerCube defuse;
in vec3 tex;

out vec4 out_Color;
void main(void) {
    out_Color = texture(defuse, tex);
}
```

CubeMap Loader

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);

int width, height, numComponents;
unsigned char* imageData = stbi_load((path.getURL() + "posx.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
stbi_image_free(imageData);
imageData = stbi_load((path.getURL() + "posy.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
stbi_image_free(imageData);
imageData = stbi_load((path.getURL() + "posz.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
stbi_image_free(imageData);
imageData = stbi_load((path.getURL() + "negx.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
stbi_image_free(imageData);
imageData = stbi_load((path.getURL() + "negy.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
stbi_image_free(imageData);
imageData = stbi_load((path.getURL() + "negz.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
stbi_image_free(imageData);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
return new GLTexture(texture);
```

Comment: You pass `stbi_load` 4 as the last argument, meaning that the image will be converted to have 4 components (if I understand correctly), yet you tell openGL that your images are only RGB (3 components). Also it would be much better if you'd tell us what OpenGL version you're using? (or up to what you're allowed to use)

Comment: Changing it to GL_RGBA fixed it! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You specify stbi to load textures with 4 components – required number of components is the last argument to `stbi_load`. You also specify to OpenGL that the textures is `GL_RGB`, which it is not. The fix to this is to either specify the texture to OpenGL as `GL_RGBA` or decode the texture as 3 components.